# Generate msdn-style website from chm file generated using DOXYGEN

Tags: documentation, doxygen, msdn

I need to document a C file and I am using DOXYGEN for that purpose. It does produce a decent output when viewed as html files but I need to have the output in msdn-style website format. The format I get from doxygen is chm. So, how can I generate MSDN-Style website format from a chm file generated using DOXYGEN ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to get a msdn-style website from a generated chm file. To create msdn style help sheets, you can prefer Sand Castle to Doxygen folks ..